# How to determine the corresponding weight of values in a categorical feature while training a Linear Regression model in tensorflow?

Tags: tensorflow, linear-regression, tensorflow-estimator

I have trained a Linear regression model using tensorflow. I have both numerical and categorical features. For this example, one of the categorical features is "has_Alt", which takes a value of either 0 or 1. When I try to get the value of the weights corresponding to this feature, I get a two dimensional vector -- [[0.23342037] [0.22178642]].

How do I know what weight corresponds to the values 0 and 1 in the provided feature.

It might be tempting to say the first is 0 and second is 1. However, what if the values were green and blue. How would we know then? Below is a code snippet of how I am adding the features.

```
def get_feature_columns(dftrain):
    CATEGORICAL_COLUMNS = ['hasAlt']

    feature_columns = []
    for feature_name in CATEGORICAL_COLUMNS:
        vocabulary = dftrain[feature_name].unique()
        feature_columns.append(tf.feature_column.categorical_column_with_vocabulary_list(feature_name, vocabulary))
    return feature_columns
```

Comment: Hi dhamechaSpeaks, can you include the rest of the code or the minimum reproducible code?

Answer (score 0):

Answer would be more clear if you would have shared the complete code.

However, have created the sample code to explain better. The values depends on the order it is present in the `vocabulary`.

**For example :**

**Code :** *If categorical column is green and blue.*

```
dftrain = {'hasAlt': ['green','blue','blue','blue','blue','blue','green','green']}
CATEGORICAL_COLUMNS = ['hasAlt']

feature_columns = []
for feature_name in CATEGORICAL_COLUMNS:
    vocabulary = set(dftrain[feature_name])
    feature_columns.append(tf.feature_column.categorical_column_with_vocabulary_list(feature_name, vocabulary))

print("Vocabulary order is :",vocabulary)
feature_columns
```

Output -

```
Vocabulary order is : {'blue', 'green'}
[VocabularyListCategoricalColumn(key='hasAlt', vocabulary_list=('blue', 'green'), dtype=tf.string, default_value=-1, num_oov_buckets=0)]
```

**Code :** *If categorical column is 0 and 1.*

```
dftrain = {'hasAlt': [1,0,0,0,0,1,1,1]}
CATEGORICAL_COLUMNS = ['hasAlt']

feature_columns = []
for feature_name in CATEGORICAL_COLUMNS:
    vocabulary = set(dftrain[feature_name])
    feature_columns.append(tf.feature_column.categorical_column_with_vocabulary_list(feature_name, vocabulary))

print("Vocabulary order is :",vocabulary)
feature_columns
```

Output -

```
Vocabulary order is : {0, 1}
[VocabularyListCategoricalColumn(key='hasAlt', vocabulary_list=(0, 1), dtype=tf.string, default_value=-1, num_oov_buckets=0)]
```

If not clear still, would request to share the complete code to explain better.

Hope this answers your question. Happy Learning.

Comment: @dhamechaSpeaks - Hope we have answered your question. Can you please accept and upvote the answer if you are satisfied with the answer.